# Android Notification onClick Activity open failed

Tags: android, sms, android-notifications

I am developing apps that can perform sending fake sms and receiving fake text message. It's better If I can use built-in SMS notification but I don't know the way. So I use my below code to generate Notification and when I click on that Notification nothing happens. Please can anyone solve my problem? I need to open Message Inbox when I click that notification. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Uri sms_uri = Uri.parse("smsto:+92xxxxxxxx");
Intent sms_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, sms_uri);
sms_intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Good Morning ! how r U ?");
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, sms_intent, 0);
Resources res = context.getResources();

Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.app_name))
        //.setContentText(res.getString(R.string.cancelText))
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email)
        .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.app_name))
        //  .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , sms_intent, 0);
```

that may help!!!

Comment: nice bro it's working.. You made  my day.. ;) many many thanks

Comment: Glad to help You!